# ¿Por que no se me ve la alerta sweetalert?

Tags: html, sweetalert

Tengo un formulario en un modal, que al pulsar en botón submit, después de validar los campos,  lo envio a un php que inserta los datos en una base de datos. Seguidamente, se notifica una alerta en la pantalla.

Este el el form

```
<form action="insertar.php" method="GET" onsubmit="return validaCampos();">                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="edad">Edad:</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="edad" name="edad" type="text" placeholder="Edad"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="direccion">Direccion:</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="direccion" name="direccion" type="text" placeholder="Direccion"></input>
                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Salvar">
               </form>
```

Este es el insertar

```
    <?php


        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "bdpersona"); 
        $nom = $_GET['nombre'];
        $edad = $_GET['edad'];
        $dir = $_GET['direccion'];                      
        $sql = $mysqli->query("insert into tbcontactos (nombre, edad, direccion) values ('$nom', $edad, '$dir') ");         

?>  

        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript"> 
        alert("Contacto Registrado"); 
        </SCRIPT> 
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=listar.php">
```

De la siguiente forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En un segundo plano se actualiza la lista y no vas a ella hasta pulsa el aceptar.

Gracias a la ayuda de vosotros sobre alertas:
He quitado la alerta *alert* y he colocado un sweetalert con los links para las las librerías, pero no me funciona, no se ejecuta. Es como si no hubiera nada
He puesto un retardo antes de redirigir a la página listar.php y ni eso.

**¿Porque no funciona la alerta?**

```
    <?php


        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "bdpersona"); 
        $nom = $_GET['nombre'];
        $edad = $_GET['edad'];
        $dir = $_GET['direccion'];                      
        $sql = $mysqli->query("insert into tbcontactos (nombre, edad, direccion) values ('$nom', $edad, '$dir') ");         

?>  

     <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-
      sweetalert2/7.8.0/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
   </script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.8.0/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>

        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript"> 
       swal(
        "Buen trabajo!",
        "El contacto ha sido registrado!",
        "success"
            );
        </SCRIPT> 
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=listar.php">
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Veo algo como que no cuadra en tu código. Como recibes la respuesta luego de insertar?

Comment: simplemente se inserta y luego vuelves a la pagina con: `URL=listar.php`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para que funcione el sweetalert tiene que estar dentro de una función de javascript o al iniciar jquery como en el ejemplo que te dejo .

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.8.0/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.8.0/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>

<script LANGUAGE="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    swal({
      title: 'Buen trabajo!',
      text: "El contacto ha sido registrado!",
      type: 'success',
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      confirmButtonText: 'OK!'
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.value) {
        window.location.href = "listar.php";
      }
    })

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Sebastián gracias!!!!! ahora funciona :) pero una cosita, se inicia pero no acaba, se redirige enseguida a listar.php , solo se ve el sweet durante milisegundos. Como se puede arreglar eso?

Comment: se podria poner que cuando pulsas aceptar del sweet se te redirige. Que opinas?

Comment: si se puede, solo tendrias que quitar ese meta refresh a la pagina de php, espera te dejo un ejemplo , modifico la respuesta y la ves vale?

Comment: listo quita el meta , y deja el código como te lo modifique ahora, avísame si funciona.

Comment: Va de lujo Sebastián. Estoy aprendiendo mucho contigo. Muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 2):

Yo lo haría de esta manera, redirecionar después que el usuario haga click en el botón de la alerta.

Espero te sirva

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
swal({
    title: "Buen trabajo!",
    text: "El contacto ha sido registrado!",
    type: "success"
   }).then(function() {
     window.location = "listar.php";
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.8.0/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.8.0/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No se me redirige :/ Debería haber algun refresh?

Comment: Pero te sale la alerta ya?

Comment: Sí. pero se queda luego en blanco la página. no se redirige

Comment: PRUEBA DE ESTA MANERA

swal({
     title: "Buen trabajo!",
     text: "El contacto ha sido registrado!",
     type: "success"
 }).then(function() {
     window.location = "listar.php";
 });

A mi me funciona de esta manera espero que a ti tambien

Comment: gracias! funciona :)